# Android app crashes when double is empty

Tags: android

I'm making triangle calculator, but when i leave any text field empty it crashes. 
Right now i want to add num2 to num4 and get answer at num1, but when i leave num1 empty it crashes.
This is my code

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1);
    EditText a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2);
    EditText a3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum4);

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum7); //P
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6); //S
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1); //a
    boolean flag = false;
    double num1, num2, num4, ans;
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(a2.getText().toString());
    num4 = Double.parseDouble(a3.getText().toString());
    ans = 0;


    //a
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) {
        flag = true;
    } else ans = num2 + num4;
    tv2.setText(ans + "");


    //S
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = num1 * num2 / 2;
    tv1.setText(ans + "");

    //P
    if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
    else ans = num1 + num2 + num4;
    tv.setText(ans + "");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

Your error is because of Null Pointer Exception, being thrown when you are calling getText on empty edittext.

Basically you are trying to use an object memory reference (of a1) with no value inside it, which is not how Java is designed. Compiler needs some value inside the memory if you are putting a reference inside the RAM.

Make sure you have  proper checks like

```
 if(a1.getText()!=null) { ...}
```

Comment: How did you know it's a `Null Pointer Exception` ?

Comment: @Rami "but when i leave any text field empty it crashes" and then gettext() call on EditText obj will throw npe

Comment: @Kay, any chance you can fix my code ? I really cant understand what u mean :/

Comment: you can go with Anggrayudi H reply, and completely ignore the exceptions, not a good idea though

Comment: @Kay: In his case i think its NumberFormatException rather than NPE... because he call  Double.parseDouble();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void onButtonClick(View v) {
        EditText a1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1);
        EditText a2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum2);
        EditText a3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFnum4);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum7); //P
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum6); //S
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TFnum1); //a
        boolean flag = false;
        double num1, num2, num4, ans;
        num1 = ParseDouble(a1.getText().toString());
        num2 = ParseDouble(a2.getText().toString());
        num4 = ParseDouble(a3.getText().toString());
        ans = 0;


        //a
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) {
            flag = true;
        } else ans = num2 + num4;
        tv2.setText(ans + "");


        //S
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = num1 * num2 / 2;
        tv1.setText(ans + "");

        //P
        if (v.getId() == R.id.Badd) if (num2 == 0) flag = true;
        else ans = num1 + num2 + num4;
        tv.setText(ans + "");
    }

private double ParseDouble(String number) {
   if (number!= null && number.length() > 0) {
       try {
          return Double.parseDouble(number);
       } catch(Exception e) {
          return -1;// Will return -1 in case of exception, you can change it with another value
       }
   } 

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks, works good, but now my S gets result 0, any idea how to fix it ?

Comment: Your "S" get 0 if the text value is *null* or *empty*... You can change *return 0;* with your desired value in this case.

Comment: if(num1!=-1){onInsertR(v, num2, num1, ans); return;} ------ this one works